# How to make templates after installing MediaWiki?

Tags: web-services, wiki, mediawiki, wikipedia

I had just installed MediaWiki. What must I do to have wikipedia style templates like this: http://i.piccy.info/i4/4b/37/fe303fda0c813c0bda717d3a1e3b.png (example). 
I have already installed ParserFunctions Extension on my MediaWiki CMS. I have tried to look source & copy it, but it didn't work. Thanks.

**sorry for my English (it isn't my native language)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you copied the source for that infobox, what you were missing was the **template** that the `{{infobox}}` tag uses, which you can find at the [Wikipedia page for the Infobox template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox).  (That page will show you the documentation on the template; `View Source` for the code you'll need to copy.)

If you want to use Wikipedia's templates, you'll need to copy them.  (Observing, of course, Wikipedia's licensing terms.)

Comment: I did this, but what I got is only: {{#if:|}} {{#if:|}}{{#if:|}}{{#if:|}}{{#if:|}}{{#if:|}} .................. (on my own page for infobox template)

Comment: Odd.  That seems as if your `ParserFunctions` extension isn't working.  I'd look into that, if I were you -- see if I could find a way of verifying that `ParserFunctions` is working.

Comment: You can check the Special:Version page to verify that ParserFunctions is installed.